Lipschitz weaker than continuity?
In my differential equations class, our Professor gave the following exercise:
(1) Suppose that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the Lipschitz Condition on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Give an example that shows that this does not guarantee that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
Lipschitz Condition: Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be some domain in which $(t_0,x_0)$ is an interior point. Then the function $f(t,x)$ defined on $D$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition on D if there exists a constant $L$ such that:
$$||f(t,x)-f(t,y)|| \leq L||x-y|| \quad(\forall (t,x), (t,y) \in D)$$
I've got a couple questions about this.
Why does this definition have the same $t$ in each case? If the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, how come that we only care about $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$? Surely we would want $f(t,x)$ to be close to $f(s,y) \quad \forall (x,t), (y,s) \in D$?
Am I right to generally think about the Lipschitz condition as meaning that the function $f$ has a bounded derivative? Are there any good intuitive sources as to why a bounded derivative implies a unique solution?
Finally, to answer (1), my professor defines $f(t,x):$
\begin{cases} 
    x & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\
    x + 1 & \text{if } t < 0 \\
\end{cases}
This answer seems to follow from the fact that the RHS of the Lipschitz condition doesn't involve t (So we can "create" discontinuities by defining an $f$ piecewise in $t$. I don't really get how we can do this though (Question above).
I also thought Lipschitz was a stronger form that simple continuity. I.e. Lipschitz implies continuity, especially when it is globally Lipschitz. How can we have a Lipschitz function that's not continuous? Am I misunderstanding these properties and in what context they apply? Thanks.
For completeness, my Professor's answer to (1): "But since the variable $t$ plays no real role in this definition, it's easy to have a non-continuous function that satisfies this [Lipschitz] condition. For instance, define $f(t,x)$ [As above]. It is easy to show that this function satisfies the Lipschitz Condition (With any $L$ at least 1). But the function is clearly not continuous in any point of the form $(0,x)$."

This is not a 'full' Lipschitz condition, this is a Lipschitz condition on one of the coordinates (namely, on the second coordinate). Thus, this does not necessarily imply continuity as normal Lipschitz does

There is a difference between Lipschitz continuity, which is stronger than uniform continuity, and the Lipschitz condition in the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE.

But why is it sufficient to have the Lipschitz condition on only one coordinate, given that our domain is $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?
